# Is there any auto recursive type inference or a modern way to do this

Tags: c++

I wanted to do a recursive evaluation tree for an interpret that returns different types depending on the evaluation in few lines and with no `void *`so here is a small example of code of what I was trying to do and didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
  node(string _text){
    child = NULL;
    sibling = NULL;
    text = _text;
  }
  node *child;
  node *sibling;
  string text;
};

auto evaluate(node *n){
  if(n->text == "sum"){
    return (int)evaluate(n->child) + (int)evaluate(n->child->sibling);
  }else if(n->text == "lt"){
    return (int)evaluate(n->child) < (int)evaluate(n->child->sibling);
  }else{
    return atoi(n->text.c_str());
  }
}

int main(){
  node sum = node("sum");
  node a_value = node("23");
  node b_value = node("13");
  sum.child = &a_value;
  sum.child->sibling = &b_value;
  cout << (int)evaluate(&sum) << endl;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a simple way to do this using modern c++.

Comment: `sum.child = &a_value;` remember that the nodes go away when the scope of `a_value` ends.

Comment: Does anything prevent you from using C++'s standard template library (STL)?

Comment: Can you use `std::any` or `std::variant`?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous.  Using `auto` as a return type is allowed only if the compiler can determine the return type at compile time.  The compiler does not appreciate being called recursively with an `auto` return type.  As all return types of evaluate are `int`, by specifying the return type explicitly, the code functions.  If this is not your intent, then you will need to do this without auto.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, but it would need to return a variant. So it's not quite what op wanted, but it's the only way to do it since return types must be determined at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, `std::any` and `std::variant` were one of my alternatives but I wasn't sure it there would be a clearer or smarter way, but it seems it will be the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

evaluate() has 3 cases, where 2 cases return an int value, and one case return a bool. A bool is implicitly convertible to int, so if return type of evaluate() is always int, it works for all cases:

```
int evaluate(const node* n)
{
    if (n->text == "sum") {
        return evaluate(n->child) + evaluate(n->child->sibling);
    }
    if (n->text == "lt") {
        return evaluate(n->child) < evaluate(n->child->sibling);
    }
    return atoi(n->text.c_str());
}
```

Comment: yes, thats one of the nifty tricks of c,  maybe I've should have posted something more complex, my evaluate function should also return lists and strings so it isn't something I could use.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is determined at compile time.  So it will never be a solution for a runtime variation. Another type of construct could be templates, but their type deduction mechanism is compile-time as well.

What you need is runtime type determination.  Here a couple of easy solutions:

- create your own `Value` class, that allow for value of different basic types to be combined.  Polymorphism could help you to implement this type in an elegant and extensible manner.
- Use an [`std::variant<...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), for example `std::variant<int, double, string>`.  The value of the variant can be any of the predefined types in the list.  This is a kind of type-safe union.  The inconvenience is that your evaluation logic will need to check the type of the variant to invoke the right operations (because operations are related to types and have to be known at compile-time).
- Use an [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).  This is very similar to the variant.  It's just more flexible, as you do not need to predefine the types that you'll allow.  But technically, for your evaluation logic, you'd still know the possible types to invoke for all possible types and combinations the right operations.

Whatever your choice will be, and not directly related to your main issue, you may be interested:

- in adding an additional parameter to  `evaluate()` to refer to the evaluation context (e.g. a symbol table, if your expression could also include variables).
- in the [interpreter pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/interpreter-pattern.html), which combines and encapsulate `node` and `evaluate()`.